# How to see default values of Apache directives?

Tags: httpd

I have switched Apache from preform mpm  to event mpm. 
Now Apache is not running out of memory but when I check *htop* I see that there are around 300 httpd processes. I know that they are dependent on ThreadsPerChild and ServerLimit directives but they are not set in any config values.

How can I see the current set values of all config options?
I tried `apachectl -S` but that is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Settings neither explicitly defined in your main `httpd.conf` nor in any additional files loaded with  the `Include` , `IncludeOptional` directives and not modified locally with a `.htaccess` file use their default values as set at compile time.

The manual documents the default values of [all directives](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/quickreference.html).

[mod_info](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html) can show you which settings Apache httpd did load from your main `httpd.conf` and from any additional files loaded with  the `Include` , `IncludeOptional` directives. You can enable either the mod_info URL or,  [dump the pre-parsed configuration to stdout during server startup](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html#startup) with the `-DDUMP_CONFIG` start-up option.

Comment: Thanks @HBruijin. I have done that but I didn't see compiled default values of directives. I know that `ServerLimit` directive has default value of 16 from the documentation but I want to know if there is an option to see the values of the running instance. For example I can check default or set values of PHP and MySQL variables.

Comment: also try `sudo apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG`.